# When are licences consumed when using Site.createPortalUser?

Tags: force.com-sites, licenses

The `Site.createPortalUser` call (see the [Site](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites.htm) class) creates the `User` object when it is called with the correct parameters. Am I correct in assuming that the underlying license is only consumed when the User object is created?

(So you only need to buy enough licenses to cover the immediate users and could buy more licences as necessary later, though perhaps at a higher unit price than if you bought a large number up front?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 types of portal / community licenses: 1st named user licenses and 2nd login-based licenses.

The login based licenses are consumed during the login. In case you implement a portal for users which try to login only once or twice a month, it will be cheaper to buy these high volume login based licenses.

In case the users will use your portal every day you should buy named user licenses.

If you want to learn more about the license model, please contact your AE.